# haskell how to print when function doesn't return IO monad?

Tags: haskell, io, monads

I following type and monad based on it:

```
data Err a = Ok a | Bad String
  deriving (Read, Show, Eq, Ord)

instance Monad Err where
  return      = Ok
  fail        = Bad
  Ok a  >>= f = f a
  Bad s >>= f = Bad s

instance Functor Err where
  fmap = liftM
```

I've also function which has ot print "asdf" to screen and end with error (this is temporary solution for debug):

```
runStatments :: [Stm] -> State -> Err State
runStatments [] state = Ok state
runStatments (s:_) state = case s of
  PrintStmt exp -> do {
    e <- evalExpression exp state;
    k <- Ok $putStrLn "asfd";
    Bad "damn!"
  }
  ...
```

The problem is that code doesn't print "asdf" on screen...

What is gentle solution for such a problem? I've tried `liftIO` and so on, but I coudln't write compileable program...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't just "jam" the IO into a monad without it bubbling up at some point. What you have to do is wrap the `Err` monad around the `IO` monad with what's called a monad transformer.

Something like

```
import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.Trans

-- If you don't like `Either`, you can change it to
-- Err
data ErrT m a = ErrT {runErrT :: m (Either String a)}

instance (Monad m, Functor m) => Monad (ErrT m) where
  return = ErrT . return . Right
  (ErrT m) >>= f = ErrT $ do
      val <- m
      case val of
          Left err -> return  $ Left err
          Right a  -> runErrT $ f a

instance MonadTrans ErrT where
  lift = ErrT . liftM Right
```

Then you can do something like this

```
test :: ErrT IO ()
test = lift $ putStrLn "Hello World"

main = runErrT test
```

Comment: What's the `Functor m` constraint for? I don't see any `fmap`s.

Comment: 1. When I change Either to Err I got error: ` 'Err' is applied to too many type arguments In the type `m (Err String a)'` 2. When I'm trying to use lift in `test` function I'm getting `Not in scope: 'lift' ` even if I import module where ErrT was defined.

Comment: @JakubKuszneruk 1. Remove the `String` argument 2. Did you import `Control.Monad.Trans`?